# Add generic value to a map in generic method in java

Tags: java, generics

I'm not that familiar with java Generics (using IntelliJ).
What I want is adding generic values to collections.
Two question for the code below.

I read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html
and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html
but don't know why the code below has an error.

Q1) I have error message in `map.put(T, T);` in add method such that red ripple under Ts: Expression Expected, introduce local variable

Q2) Wondering in this case, should I declare class as `public class Test<T>` or can I declare `public class Test`?

```
public class Test<T> {
Map<T, T> map;


public Test() {
    map = new HashMap<T, T>();        
}

public <T> void add(T value) throws Exception {
    map.put(value, value);  // Q1) red ripple under value: Expression Expected, introduce local variable

}
}
```

Comment: Remove `<T>` from your method. You're hiding the class parameter.

Comment: Did you mean map.put(value, value)?

Comment: Also you can't `put(T, T)`. Maybe you meant `put(value, value)`?

Comment: Can you give some context? What is the class Test for? Without some more information it’s impossible to answer question 2.

Comment: ah, sorry, it was typo. of course what I meant was `map.put(value, value); `

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in here.

1. The generic method parameter `T` hides the class one `T`. They are different types and you have no ways to refer to that `T` (unless you rename one of them).
2. The method `map.put` expects values of `T` type, not this type itself (it is not an instance of `Class` anyway).

The solution:

```
public void add(T value) throws Exception {
    map.put(value, value);
}
```

> Wondering in this case, should I declare class as `public class Test<T>` or can I declare `public class Test`?

You don't necessarily need to declare class generic types if you want few generic methods - make your methods with their own generic types. Note that there won't be any resemblance between them.

But, in your case, a generic type `T` is mandatory since you declared a generic field `Map<T, T> map`.